# Непонятная ситуация с Espresso. IllegalStateException

Tags: android, espresso

В общем начал разбираться с Espresso.   Написал кастомный раннер

```
public class CustomRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MockApplication.class.getName(), context);
    }
}
```

кусок градла

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "ru.packadge.CustomRunner"

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 115
    versionName "2.4.3"
    multiDexEnabled true    
} 

dependencies {

    /*=====================================================
    =================== TEST LIBRARY =====================
    =====================================================*/
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.2.0'


    /*=====================================================
    ================= COMMON LIBRARIES ====================
    ======================================================*/
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0') { force = true }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.2.1@aar"
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.4'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.1.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14' exclude module: 'httpclient'

    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.1+'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.11'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'droidkit:droidkit:3.3.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'  exclude module: 'javax.inject'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2' exclude module: 'javax.inject'

}
```

Самое странно, при запуске падает с ошибкой  и все. в гугле ничего не нашел                                      вообще. может можно флаги задать, чтобы можно было побольше инфы вытащить?

```
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalStateException'
```

Comment: Вот за это я не люблю всякие юнит тестеры - вместо того, чтобы разрабатывать надо еще и отлаживать сами тесты, а потом еще писать прилады для тестирования тестов :)

Comment: Попробуйте запустить gradle с --full-stacktrace